# Way to move all non photos and video out of photos library

Tags: terminal, photos, filesystem

I have a photos library.

Somehow the library has unsupported file types in it. These files to not show up in the photos app.

I am looking for a way to move these files out of the library.

An example of this would be if I drop a .txt file in the library.

My concern is that I may merge many libraries and loose files along the way.

Is there anyway to move all unsupported files from photos? Ideally using terminal.

Comment: First of all, dropping a file on the Photos Library, e.g. "$HOME/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary", does not allow the file to pass into it. Secondly, the Photos Library contain many files that do not show up in Photos. So unless you actually open the Photos Library by e.g. right-click > Show Package Contents and then dropped some files into it, there should be nothing in there besides what's supposed to be in there.

Comment: Yep opening it up and dropping it in is what I meant. Somehow I have files that shouldn't be in there like audio files. I'm not sure how it happened. I just want a way to clean the library.

Comment: Here is a partial list of valid file extension that can be found in the Photos Library... `.AAE`, `.HEIC`, `.MOV`, `.PNG`, `.cmap`, `.data`, `.db`, `.db-shm`, `.db-wal`, `.graphdb`, `.graphdb-shm`, `.graphdb-wal`, `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, `.lij`, `.lock`, `.mov`, `.plist`, `.skindex` and there are valid files without any extension too. I think it might be easier to manually remove files that don't belong there; however, that also is predicated on knowing what one is doing!